# decryption of mysql column in .net

Tags: mysql, c#-4.0, encryption

I have a column in mysql called reference column which is encrypted. I have the key for decryption. I am retriving the data using entityframework and need to decryption the column and push it to a csv file. can some one help me with the decryption code using c#

```
public string DecryptStringFromBytes(string value)
{
    String encryptKey = "Youare@IsBe$t";
    byte[] key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encryptKey);
    byte[] cipherText = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);

    string plaintext = null;
    using (RijndaelManaged rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged())
    {
        rijAlg.GenerateIV();

        ICryptoTransform decryptor = rijAlg.CreateDecryptor(key, rijAlg.IV);

        using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
        {
            using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                {
                    plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return plaintext;
}
```

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: added my present code

Comment: Have a look here, https://simpledotnetsolutions.wordpress.com/2012/03/22/using-rijndaelmanaged-to-encryptdecrypt/